# Many lines through the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me to draw a figure of many lines through the origin

[image]

like the above figure but without the plan, and the dashed parts. I wish to create an effect of a line in movement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way using the `3dtools` library from [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools). Maybe one fine day when GitHub becomes more accessible to users with some math background this library will become part of CTAN... This library allows us to access the coordinates and compute the intersection with the plane analytically.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,perspective,3d,3dtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{15}]
 \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O) 
  foreach \X[count=\Y] in {(3,0,0),(2,1,1),(2,0,3),(1,1,3),(0,0,3)}
   {(O) -- \X coordinate (p\Y) coordinate[pos=-0.3] (p-\Y)};
 \path[canvas is xy plane at z=2,fill=blue!30] (
 (-4,-4) coordinate (r1) -- (4,-4) coordinate
 (r2) -- (4,4)  coordinate
 (r3) -- (-4,4) -- cycle;
 \path[name path=edge] (r1) -- (r2)  -- (r3); 
 \foreach \Y in {1,...,5}
 {\path[name path=ray] (p-\Y) -- (p\Y);
 \path[name intersections={of=edge and ray,total=\t},draw,thick]
 \ifnum\t=1
  (p-\Y) -- (intersection-1) coordinate (i-\Y)
 \else 
  (p-\Y) -- (p\Y)
 \fi;
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\itest}{TD("(p\Y)o(0,0,1)")}
 \ifdim\itest pt>0pt
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tt}{2/TD("(p\Y)o(0,0,1)")}
  \ifdim\tt pt<1pt
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myint}{TD("\tt*(p\Y)")}
   \draw[thick,dashed] (\myint) -- (i-\Y);
   \draw[thick] (\myint) node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill]{} -- (p\Y);
  \fi
 \fi
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds über cool! Note that if you don't want to store a generated PDF file in the repository, I've found that you can still offer it for download on GitHub by uploading it to a wiki (GitHub wiki for your project; for example, see *Instructions and examples* for [expsagetex](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex)—that section has a [link](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/wiki/files/expsagetex.pdf) to the rendered manual in PDF format) .

Comment: @frougon There are basically two versions of manuals. Either they assume you are a computing expert or they assume that you are super dumb and cannot even add two numbers. It would be great if there was something that does not assume you are a computing expert but also does not assume you do not know any math or logic.

Comment: Mmm, yeah, but I'm not sure I see the connection with what I wrote. Do you mean that my link to the PDF in `README.md` is too difficult to discover, and that an in-repo generated PDF next to the `.tex` avoids the problem of users not finding the already-compiled documentation?

Comment: @frougon Yes, you are right, I am just frustrated with GitHub.

Comment: Right, their interface has a few problems for making documentation accessible, indeed. I struggled to find this wiki thing, and even then, it's not perfect.